# No provider for "NgComponentOutlet"

Tags: angular, ng-component-outlet

I have an Angular 11 application, which imports `@angular/material`, `@ngx-translate`, and a lib called [icell-data-table](https://github.com/i-Cell-Mobilsoft-Open-Source/icell-data-table#readme).

Downloading the example project from the github page I was able to start it witout any problems on my local environment.

But upon extracting it to a Stadckblitz demo, I have encountered a strange error:

```
Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@11.1.1/bundles/compiler.umd.js (3057:21)
Template parse errors:
No provider for NgComponentOutlet ("onentTemplate [cellTemplate]="'componentTemplate'" let-row="row" let-col="col" let-idx="rowIdx">
[ERROR ->]<ng-container
*ngComponentOutlet="col.component; ndcDynamicInputs: getComponentInputs(row, col);"): ng:///DataTableModule/CellTemplatesComponent.html@23:2
```

The [Stackblitz project can be found here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/icell-datatable-demo-ng11?file=src/app/app.module.ts). Any ideas about what is missing from it?

**Update 1:**
as @yurzui pointed out, there were incompatible dependencies in `icell-data-table` and Angular 11. I have updated the lib with a proper dependency to [ng-dynamic-component](https://github.com/i-Cell-Mobilsoft-Open-Source/icell-data-table/blob/7f9ecf701bd7675df7a20469632e508f9569a136/package.json#L41), which is now the Angular11 version (^8.0.0) of now.

But the stackblitz example still displays the error :(

Comment: Check the versions of all dependencies and config are in sync in the two environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that in stackblitz you have two versions of `@angular/common` package.

```
@angular/common@11.1.1
@angular/common@9.1.13
```

The former is used when Angular is registering providers, the latter comes into play when it is time to resolve provider.

Let's take a look at why Angular can't resolve that `NgComponentOutlet` token. Here's a simple explanation:

```
import { NgComponentOutlet as outlet1 } from "@angular/common@11.1.1";
import { NgComponentOutlet as outlet2 } from "@angular/common@9.1.3";
 

const providers = new Map();
providers.set(outlet1, 'Any value');

console.log(providers.has(outlet2)); // false
```

The `NgComponentOutlet` class is defined in both bundles and they even look the same but since Angular uses `Map` object to resolve providers it fails due to in `Map` key equality is based on the [sameValueZero algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value-zero_equality)

Now, why do we have two versions of Angular package in stackblitz. That because `@i-cell/data-table` uses `ng-dynamic-component@6.1.0` which [depends on Angular 9](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component)

So, once you solve this versions incompatibility you should get smth like **[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/icell-datatable-demo-ng11-yyniqt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)**

Comment: I will look into the said lib and update the dependency properly next week, awesome that you pointed that out! Just for curiosity: can you please tell me what did you exactly update in the forked example to make it work in it's current state?

Comment: I intercepted save http request and substituted incompatible dependencies

Comment: I have updated the `icell-data-table` project to depend on the proper version of `ng-dynamic-component@8.0.1` and published the new version of the lib. However, the problem still persists :(

Comment: Now the problem is that stackblitz resolves dependencies for ng-dynamic-component as `@angular/common@11.1.2` but you're running `11.1.1` version.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/icell-datatable-demo-ng11-8gxpft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts I updated `@angular/core` and `@angular/common` to 11.1.2, replaced AppComponent selector with `my-app` and added `RouterModule.forRoot([])`to root NgModule

Comment: really appreciate that you went ahead and fixed it. Although it seems to have some minor visual issues, it's working now - thanks for the help!